# Cannot run python script requiring matplotlib on Raspberry Pi3b+

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying for the last 2 days to run the following Python script which requires matplotlib to plot live data from a sensor, but with no success.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smbus
import math
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Power management registers
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c
incl = []
plt.ion
def makefig():
    plt.plot(incl,'ro-')

def read_byte(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)

def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))

def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)

def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # or bus = smbus.SMBus(1) for Revision 2 boards
address = 0x68       # This is the address value read via the i2cdetect command
while True:
    # Now wake the 6050 up as it starts in sleep mode
    bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)

    gyro_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
    gyro_yout = read_word_2c(0x45)
    gyro_zout = read_word_2c(0x47)

    #print ("gyro_xout: ", gyro_xout, " scaled: ", (gyro_xout / 131))
    #print ("gyro_yout: ", gyro_yout, " scaled: ", (gyro_yout / 131))
    #print ("gyro_zout: ", gyro_zout, " scaled: ", (gyro_zout / 131))



    accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
    accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
    accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)

    accel_xout_scaled = accel_xout / 16384.0
    accel_yout_scaled = accel_yout / 16384.0
    accel_zout_scaled = accel_zout / 16384.0

    #print ("accel_xout: ", accel_xout, " scaled: ", accel_xout_scaled)
    #print ("accel_yout: ", accel_yout, " scaled: ", accel_yout_scaled)
    #print ("accel_zout: ", accel_zout, " scaled: ", accel_zout_scaled)
    #my_incl = (get_x_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))
    #incl.appned(my_incl)
    #drawnow(makefig)
    #plt.pause(0.00001)
   # print ("x rotation: " , '{0:.0f}'.format(my_incl))

    #print ("y rotation: " , get_y_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))
```

When running the above, I get the following error from numpy:

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/car/car.py", line 7, in 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 32, in 
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 28, in 
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 11, in 
    from .path import Path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 17, in 
    from . import _path, rcParams
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

It seems to me that I have a wrong version of numpy. 
But still after updating numpy, uninstalling, reinstalling, searching for help here etc. (not all at the same try, each one as a seperate try) I still dont know how to fix this...

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: are there multiple python versions installed? are you sure python3.5 is what you want? did you use pip3? Just ideas

Comment: Yes. Both python 2.something and 3.5.3 (Typical installation of Stretch on RPi).
I used `sudo pip3 install matplotlib ` to get it on...